# python regex, only return 1st numerical match

Tags: python, regex

im using Python regex.  i have a situation that the text doesnt always return the same text in order to run my regex on. the text can come in 4 different options.  i just need to return numerical value including any decimals

if it is the 1st 2 options it straight forward. if its the 3rd/4th option, it matches both.  i only need to return the 1st occurrence, regardless if it has a decimal or not, just the first.  i have this regex, but it matches both occurrences, i only need 1st occurrence.

what can i add to this regex in order to return the first occurrence (or whats better regex for my issue)

My regex is `[approx. |Current ] distance(\d+\.?\d+) miles`

```
option1
Curent distance4124 miles
>> regex output = 4124

option2
approx. distance4124 miles
>> regex output = 4124

option3
approx. distance4124.2 miles
Current distance4124 miles
>> regex output = 4124.2

options4
Current distance4124 miles
approx. distance4124.2 miles
>> regex output = 4124
```

Comment: You need round parentheses, not square brackets.This is a common enough beginner error that it's explained in [the `regex` tag info page.](/tags/regex/info)

Comment: thanks trip, but i changed the [ ] to ( ) and got nothing in return. keeping [ ] matches both in option3 & 4 above. changing to ( ) matches nothing

Comment: Again, read the information behind the link to understand the difference. (The reason it stops matching is that you then require two successive spaces.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Solution

There is a `re.finditer(pattern, string, flags=0)` in python which:

```
Return an iterator yielding match objects over all non-overlapping 
matches for the RE pattern in string. The string is scanned left-to- 
right, and matches are returned in the order found. Empty matches are 
included in the result.
```

The first match object can be obtained using `next(match_object)`.

---

### Error

Please note that your regex is incorrect.

- As @tripleee mentioned in the comments, *you have to use `(...|...)` for alternation and not `[...]`*.
- *The part where are matching a decimal number is also incorrect*. It should be `\d+(\.\d+)?`. Your regex will not match for the string `approx. distance4 miles`.
- *You have also used extra space in your regex which results in failed matching*.

---

### Code

*regex used:* `\d+(?:\.\d+)?`

Using this regex in `findall` will return all the numbers found in the input text, hence I have used `finditer`. You can also use `search`.

```
import re

line = input()
match = re.finditer("\d+(?:\.\d+)?", line)
print()
print(next(match).group(0))
```

---

### Sample IO

```
Input 1:
approx. distance4124.2 miles
Current distance4124 miles

Output 1:
4124.2

Input 2:
Current distance4124 miles

Output 2:
4124
```

---

If you face any other problems, do comment.

Comment: i just need the entire numerical value , just the first occurrence. (my fault in the explanation). so match should be 4124.2 not the entire line. another issue is i have 10 regex i run against a string, just is just 1 of them, so the function is :
for rx in regxlist:
        matches += re.findall(rx, a, flags=re.DOTALL)
so i cant do a group(index#).... thats why i wanted to edit the regex itself to find 1st match

Comment: @jonrios I suggest using `re.finditer(pattern, string, flags=0)`. It will return match objects for all the regexes. They can be used to obtain whatever you desire. Editing the regex is not an easy task. I am also looking for the regex solution part. *Will this text appear at the start of the string? Or it can appear in the middle?*

Comment: playing around i came up with this one and it seems to work, but wanted to check with you. "(?<!distance)[approx. |Current ]distance(\d*\.?\d*?) (?<!miles)"ms

Comment: Isn't distance part of a match? Also why have you used `[...]`? Checking for decimal number part can also be improved.